# How long will glutinous rice flour keep unopened?

Tags: rice, flour

I have one unopened bag of glutinous rice flour, it's 1 year old, I know rice keeps well for a very long time and was wondering if this also applies to rice flour?

Answer (score 2):

As per [this website](http://www.eatbydate.com/other/baking/how-long-does-flour-last-shelf-life-expiration-date/): it should last 6-8 months past printed expiration date.

However, [this website](https://www.recipetips.com/kitchen-tips/t--1039/flour-storage-guide.asp) says that when stored in a tightly covered container in a cool dry place, white rice flour may last indefinitely. You can also have a look at [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33959/should-flour-be-thrown-out-past-its-expiry-date) which talks about bugs and rancidity.

I have previously kept rice flour in a plastic container inside the fridge and it's lasted me quite long, way past it's expiration date.