# Flour is many years expired but still looks good

Tags: food-safety, flour, spoilage

I have a bag of flour in my pantry that expired 3 years ago, but it looks and smells perfectly fine. Is it still safe to eat?

EDIT: To clarify, today is July 3rd, 2018, and the flour best before date is "2015 SE 04"

Question is different from other existing questions on the topic because the duration of time passed is more extreme (other questions describe a few months).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should flour be thrown out past its expiry date?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33959/should-flour-be-thrown-out-past-its-expiry-date)

Comment: It *usually* starts to smell rancid, and you've given the inevitable bug eggs 3 years to hatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against the use of that. However, it's still okay to a certain extent as it is only a best before date - not use by.

Comment: 3 years is a long time, but as stated, that is not an expire date.  "Best By" means that in the packer's opinion, after that date the product will start to deteriorate.  How much it deteriorates and how quickly is opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I am using flour that expired in 2018. I had to use some of my emergency flour due to the corona virus shortages. Its pretty good but not as good as fresh. Id say 90% as good tasting. Yeast on the other hand is different. Ive had a one pound block of yeast in the freezer since 2014 and it still works. Not very well but it works. I have to double up the amount and wait twice as long so the bread tastes very yeasty but it is good to know it can last this long.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 4year old bag of seasoned flour, A-No-1 seasoned flour, I use brand all the time so must have bought too much lol, but it was ok, I add a little baking powder and salt it's same., Was too much money to throw away before trying lol